# Csv-file line changes to appear in webshop

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv

I have a csv-file that has items like this:

```
"";"";"";"";"Park2";"Lamella Koivu Natur Loc 5 3-sauvainen 14x188x2266mm. 3,41m2/PKT.";"PKT";"2";"100,0000";"-596,7500";"1";"0";"Lamella Koivu Natur Loc

- Ruotsalainen, laadukas
- 5G Lukkoponttiparketti, taitettava/painettava
- Helppo asentaa
- 3-sauvainen, mattalakattu
- Lauta 14x188x2266mm
- 3,41m2/pkt, 102,3m2/lava

29,33€/M2";""
```

What I need is the output to be like this:

```
"";"";"";"";"Park2";"Lamella Koivu Natur Loc 5 3-sauvainen 14x188x2266mm. 3,41m2/PKT.";"PKT";"2";"100,0000";"-596,7500";"1";"0";"Lamella Koivu Natur Loc<br>
<br>
- Ruotsalainen, laadukas<br>
- 5G Lukkoponttiparketti, taitettava/painettava<br>
- Helppo asentaa<br>
- 3-sauvainen, mattalakattu<br>
- Lauta 14x188x2266mm<br>
- 3,41m2/pkt, 102,3m2/lava<br>
<br>
29,33€/M2";""
```

Or something else that would work, it does not to be exactly like this. I tested adding br manually and it worked. I just want the item descriptions to have line changes in the webstore. Now they do not, line changes are removed in the importing process (import component in joomla cms).

I am creating the csv-file from a .txt file in a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ csvsql -H -d ';' --query "SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,REPLACE(m, char(10), '<br>'||char(10)),n FROM data" data.csv
```

This uses [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/) to treat the CSV file as a database table, and selects all columns (named `a` through to `n` for a total of 14 anonymous columns). It replaces the literal newlines (`char(10)`) in column 13 (`m`) with `<br>` followed by newline.

Result:

```
,,,,Park2,"Lamella Koivu Natur Loc 5 3-sauvainen 14x188x2266mm. 3,41m2/PKT.",PKT,2,1000000,-5967500,1,0,"Lamella Koivu Natur Loc<br>
<br>
- Ruotsalainen, laadukas<br>
- 5G Lukkoponttiparketti, taitettava/painettava<br>
- Helppo asentaa<br>
- 3-sauvainen, mattalakattu<br>
- Lauta 14x188x2266mm<br>
- 3,41m2/pkt, 102,3m2/lava<br>
<br>
29,33€/M2",
```

If you want `;`-delimiters in the output, pass the result over to `csvformat`:

```
$ csvsql -H -d ';' --query "SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,REPLACE(m, char(10), '<br>'||char(10)),n FROM data" data.csv | csvformat -D ';'
;;;;Park2;Lamella Koivu Natur Loc 5 3-sauvainen 14x188x2266mm. 3,41m2/PKT.;PKT;2;1000000;-5967500;1;0;"Lamella Koivu Natur Loc<br>
<br>
- Ruotsalainen, laadukas<br>
- 5G Lukkoponttiparketti, taitettava/painettava<br>
- Helppo asentaa<br>
- 3-sauvainen, mattalakattu<br>
- Lauta 14x188x2266mm<br>
- 3,41m2/pkt, 102,3m2/lava<br>
<br>
29,33€/M2";
```

Comment: May want to add `-U1` to the csvformat, if the OP wants to force the quoting.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -0pe 's/("[^"]*")(?=[;\n])/ $1 =~ s!\n!<br>\n!gr /gse' ex.csv
```

- `perl -0pe` ... slurp the input and in the end print the result
- `s/("[^"]*")(?=[;\n])/  action-perl   /ge` ... substitute all strings by the result of...
- `$1 =~ s!\n!<br>\n!gr` replacing the newlines by `<br>\n`

Answer (score 0):

Using `gawk`, where [`RS` (the record separator) may be a regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#gawk-split-records).

```
BEGIN {
    RS="\"\n"
}
{
    gsub("\n","<br>\n")
    print
}
```

This assumes that a `"` at the end of a line is the end of the record, but that pattern could also match a newline at the start of a field.  When that happens, no `<br>` will be inserted there.

Other versions of `awk` may not support this.  From the [`awk` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/awk.html):

> If RS contains more than one character, the results are unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

I like ruby and its CSV module:

```
ruby -e '
  require "csv"
  options = {:col_sep => ";", :force_quotes => true}
  new_csv = CSV.generate(options) {|csv|
    CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift, options) {|row|
      row[-2].gsub!(/\n/, "<br>\n")
      csv << row
    }
  }
  puts new_csv
' file.csv
```